# How to remove old (out commented) msgid from po files?

Tags: python, gettext

I'm quite new to the GNU gettext tools. So please feel free to correct me if I use the wrong terms.

In my Python code I modified `_("Every 30 minutes")` to `_("Every {n} minutes").format(...)`.
Updating the `pot` (po-template) via `xgettext` worked well. The old msgid totally disapeared in that file and the new msgid appeared.

But then updating my `po` files based on the `pot` (using `msgmerge --update`) do confuse me. The old msgid do not disappear but is just out commented.

```
#~ msgid "Every 30 minutes"
```

Can I influence that behaviour somehow and prevent `msgmerge` from creating them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no such option to `msgfmt` but all obsolete entries - that is what they are called - are at the end of the file and you can easily remove them with a text editor.

Obsolete are kept in the `.po` file because they can always be re-activated, when the message in question re-appears in your sources. Likewise, they can be used as the base for a fuzzy entry if a new string resembles an obsolete one.  Most people keep the obsolete entries for that reason.